# How to access validator declared in reactive form group when in scope of a custom control?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have custom component (which I'm satisfied with) and using it in a reactive form like this.

```
private init() {
  const control4 = new FormControl("yy", Validators.pattern(".{2}"));
  const control5 = new FormControl("zz", Validators.pattern(".{3}"));

  this.form = new FormGroup({
    c4: control4,
    c5: control5
  });
}
```

The error messaging takes place in the main component and I can access the errors there. However, I'd like to add some functionality to the custom component reacting to it being invalid.

```
<input id="c4" formControlName="c4">
<app-textbox formControlName="c5"></app-textbox>
```

One way to do so is to provide `NG_VALIDATOR` marker in the decorator of *app-textbox* and push a reference to self. However, that will **amend** a validator to the one already provided in the main component's setup shown above. I googled but got nothing useful as most of hits drowned in the custom component and custom validator examples.

Is it possible to access the validator, the error raised or the regex used in the reactive form setup while in the scope of the custom control being reacted to?

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-textbox', ... ,
  providers: [
    //{ provide: NG_VALIDATOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ...), multi: true }, 
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ...), multi: true }]
})
export class TextboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  ...
  private showMeTheStuff() {
    // access the validator, regex or error raised
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you implemented the ControlValueAccessor's interfaces like 'writeValue', 'registerOnChange', 'registerOnTouched', etc. ? because like that you might have complete access control to the FormGroup you are working with... You could also decouple the main FormGroup into 2 pieces : One MainComponent's FormGroup and another ChildComponent's FormGroup and merge them inside MainComponent's ngAfterViewInit method.

Comment: @PedroB. Yes, I implemented the interface `ControlValueAccessor ` and it's working as supposed to (changes in the custom component are correctly propagated in the form component where the form group is deeclared). Now, you say that I can have full access to the form group I'm working with. Is that from within the custom component? I can't see how. I checked all the properties I could thing of... Helping hand here, please?

Comment: Only idea I have now is that if you want to have access to the form inside your custom component just pass the MainComponent's FormGroup (this.form) to your custom component as an @Input...

Comment: @PedroB. It's actually a nifty idea, better than the one I had. As to my exact question, it's a no-go, then. I wanted to know if I can access the validator of the form group's control in the custom control **only by the power of** it being reacted to. It's quite likely that it's not possible but I still wanted to check with the community. Please post your comment as an answer to be accepted. I'll post a bounty in a few days and if nobody else comes up with something better than your suggestion, you can have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be done by using the injector and the appropriate hooks, import Injector and NgControl and do this:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const ctrl = this.injector.get(NgControl, null)
  console.log(ctrl)
}
```

The ctrl there will be the form control directive assigned to your custom control. this may be form control name, a form control, or a formgroup, etc. you'll have to figure it out once there and handle the cases you're interested in (probably jsut form control and form control name). you'll have access to the control and it's methods / properties and any parent as well.

Alternatively, you can inject the ControlContainer:

`constructor(private ctrl: ControlContainer) { }`

probably wana mark as optional and all that though.  this will give you the parent form group directive which has access to all the same things.

Comment: That was a rather advanced answer. Good stuff. I haven't used *Injector* nor *ControlContainer* before, not explicitly, at least. Would you be able to shed some light on them so an ignorant developer can decide between those two?

Comment: The injector is just angulars injector but it allows you to Delay the injection. That is needed here because the NgControl directive isn’t available here until after the view has initialized. You’ll get static injector errors if you try to inject normally. ControlContainer is the topmost parent control holding the current directive. You can inject it normally because it’s higher in the tree than the actual control. The more appropriate one depends what you want, the control? Then use the injector and ng control. The entire form group? Use control container

Comment: Also a more low level thing I may have taken for granted in this explanation, directive instances can always be injected into child elements just like service instances. They’re provided based on where they’re placed in the component tree. That’s what we’re doing here, injecting the formGroup or formControlName directives. The form control name just needs to be delayed because it’s ON the component you’re trying to inject it into so it’s initializing at the same time. The container is already initialized though so it can be injected safely.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the best approach but at least it's something:

If you want to have access to the FormGroup inside your custom component (child) just pass the MainComponent's FormGroup **(this.form)** to your custom component as an **@Input**... Then you will have access to the entire [FormGroup API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) from your variable.

like `<app-textbox [form]="form" formControlName="c5"></app-textbox>`

and catching the MainComponent's form like `@Input() form: FormGroup;` inside your child (TextBoxComponent)

Comment: Good. It's definitely a workaround worth keeping as a part of the answers, so +1. In the actual case, we need to pass the actual *FormControl* (i.e. the component reacted to), rather than the *FormGroup* (i.e. the form). I noticed the restriction when I used your suggestion and my component had no clue which of the validators related to it, hehe. Your answer is still valid but requires a bit of thinking (as opposed to just copy), which I find delighting.